# Ultegra FC-R8000 Chainring Bolt Fatigue

Tags: shimano, chainring

As per my troubleshooting to find a bike creak ([Ultegra FC-R8000 Right Crank Arm Creak](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/62629/ultegra-fc-r8000-right-crank-arm-creak)) - I have installed and removed the same chainring bolts ~8 times. In the process I snapped one of them. Each of my installs have used a torque wrench at 14Nm with a Torx T30 bit.

I have noticed that when installed on a crank it seems more difficult to push the T30 into the bolt, but when they are removed it is easy to slide the bit into the bolts.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour from these (or other Shimano) chainring bolts? Am I doing something wrong if this is happening?

Comment: Did you buy the crankset from the LBS you mentioned in the other question?  Was the one that snapped from the old crankset or the new crankset?

Comment: I did buy the cranks from my LBS. The one I snapped was from the old crankset. The new set came with a new set of bolts so I used one from there. I'll update the other question with this - but I did try all 4 new bolts in my troubleshooting as well.

Comment: Good work - I'd replace all the bolts if one has snapped.

Comment: the bolts sound like they are made of cheese just to save a few grammes of weight.  Buy some steel bolts instead

Answer (score 2):

Just sheared one of mine on an Ultegra R8020 11-speed crank. It's a Torx 30 screw made of aluminium, so it sheared quite easily when I tightened it to the Shimano recommended 12 - 16 NM. This seems far too much and even 8 NM seems too much.

I managed to get a Sora screw, which gets me back on the road, from the LBS and they recommend 6 NM with alloy screws.

Comment: I also had a creak in my Ultegra crank which I'm still trying to sort out. I switched a Praxis Zayante crank for the Ultegra yet even with a new BB it still creaks. I tightened the chainring bolts (and snapped one - see previous post) but when checking the box of bits left over from the swap I noticed a spacer on one of the Praxis BB cups,the Ultegra doesn't have this so I think adding the spacer could solve the problem - I'm doing this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve sheared off 5 now on my ultegra 6800 send Duraace 9100 at 13NM.  Took spec recommended by Shimano seems way too high.

Just called Shimano. They said the torque setting is correct and are sending me 8 new bolts FOC. One thing I noticed was that the Trek dealership that did my inspection on both units must have applied some grease when reinstalling bc there was a big clump of red grease in each bolt socket. Shimano rep recommended not using any grease as could lead to over torking??

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Can you confirm the source and type of the bolts you were using?

Comment: They were what ever bolts Shimano provides with the original component new. I believe they are alloy they were both black on the Ultegra and DA whereas I noticed on 105 the bolts are silver.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - the best answer I've been able to come up with/figure out is that when I was torquing the bolts down I might have been putting force on both the crank arm and the torque wrench and maybe doubling up on the force...

Comment: 'Every force has a equal and opposite reaction.' To tighten a chainring bolt you have to put an equal torque on the crank to keep it from rotating, that does not mean the torque is doubled.

Comment: I agree with Argenti, it does not seem likely. Shimano’s specs for the R8K cranks do say 12-16 Nm of torque. Ultegra should have steel bolts as well, which I’d expect to be more resistant to fatigue. Best guess is just a faulty bolt, unless your torque wrench is terribly miscalibrated.

Comment: Hmm. I found a site that said that the 6800 version of Ultegra uses alloy chainring bolts, so I'd assume the current generation also does. Again, if the OP used the correct torque, these should not have cracked, but I do wonder if failures may be more common with alloy bolts. Most users don't need to repeatedly install chainrings. https://handsonbike.blogspot.com/2016/10/shimano-ultegra-6800-vs-shimano-105.html