# Clicking while pedalling

Tags: pedals

Hi all while I'm pedalling I get clicking noise I feel it in the left side of pedal I change the pedals I thought that may of been the problem  but it's still there but funniest  thing is if I stand up on the bike while pedalling  the noise isn't  there any ideas?

Comment: Does your bike have a press fit BB?  They are notorious for issues like this.

Comment: Also typical for SRAM GXP bottom brackets. Please tell us more about your bike and your bottom bracket.

Comment: Did you check your knees?

Comment: Clicks like these are super hard to diagnose. I wrote [an answer to a question about creaks](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/12754/4239) (which are usually caused by the same things) that you may find helpful. Also, check out the "Related" column to the right side of the page.

Answer (score 5):

If the clicking stops when you stand up, the first suspects are the parts you sit on: saddle and seat post.

Comment: But as I pedal sat down I feel the clicking  in the left  pedal but I will check the seat

Comment: If it can be felt in the pedal, then its most likely Pedal/Crank/BB.
But it's definitely worth trying to rule out the saddle rails.

Comment: If the clicking stops when you stand up, the bottom bracket is not eliminated. The bottom bracket is loaded differently when you put your weight on both pedals, compared to sitting on the saddle and just pushing on one pedal.  The frame flex around the crank is different also.

Comment: If you read carefully, I didn't write that bottom bracket is eliminated. Just that the saddle and seat post are first suspects.

Answer (score 2):

Your crank arm or arms could be loose or the bottom bracket retaining ring might be loosening as well. You will need to do a diagnostic on the whole crank assembly to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

Check your spokes. I recently had a click and it turned out to be a broken spoke. Didn't sound like it at all.

Just something to check. I don't have a good explanation why the sound might change when you stand up on the pedals other than that standing up shifts weight on the bicycle. It might unload the rear wheel a bit causing that spoke to move around just a little bit differently. I have broken quite a few spokes and while sometimes the sound is a recognizable 'ting ting' this is not always the case. Sound may not even be in step with the rotation of the wheel.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange - you raise a good point that wasn't already mentioned in the other answers.   If it is a spoke, then how might you explain why the noise goes away when OP stands to pedal ?  Use [edit] to expand your answer.